# How can I increment a number in a shortcode once a day?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on an e-commerce deal site using woocommerce, and I would like to set up my deals in advanced. To start, I am displaying 1 product a day in a static homepage using the woocommerce shortcode:

```
[product_page id="1"]
```

How can I get the id to increment once a day, so that a new product is displayed every day? Are there any good extensions that allow me to force a WordPress page to edit itself every day?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use `[recent_products per_page="1" columns="1"]` ?

Comment: This doesn't work. It shows a single product, but it's in a category view. It needs to be in a product details view.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shortcode to show one recent product. So that the recently added one product will be show on the page.

Use `new WP_Query( $args )` with

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 );
```

Please refer the [link](http://sivasankar.in/wordpress-shortcode-to-list-post-with-multiple-parameters/) for more details. You can also refer [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way without shortcode.

```
echo WC_Shortcodes::product_page( array( 'id' => 1) );
```